# Blocking a user in ASP.NET using timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout

I am trying to make a login page using ASP.NET. i want to block a user for 5 minutes after 3 failed login attempts. I didn't use a login control in my page,so I guess I can't use a membership provider. What I want to do is the following:

- set a *counter* to 0 and a bool called *accept_login* to true
- every time my *ValidatePassword* function returns 0,the *counter* increments
- when *counter*'s value is 3, set *accept_login* on false,reset *counter* and start a timeout for 5 minutes

Below is the code I wrote without implementing these things. Could someone help me integrate them? Thanks!

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using BCryptLibrary;
    using System.Web.Security;

    namespace BootstrapRegisterLogin
    {
        public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConectionString1"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {

                    using (SqlCommand verifica = new SqlCommand())
                    {


                        con.Open();
                        verifica.CommandText = "select * from [Users] where Username=@nume_ut";
                        verifica.Parameters.Add("@nume_ut", UserName.Text);
                        verifica.Connection = con;
                        verifica.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        using (SqlDataReader rd = verifica.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (rd.Read())
                            {
                                if (Hasher.ValidatePassword(Password.Text, rd[2].ToString()))
                                {
                                    con.Close();
                                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(verifica);
                                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                                    sda.Fill(dt);

                                    if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
                                    {

                                        string Utype;
                                        Utype = dt.Rows[0][6].ToString().Trim();                                 

                                        if (Utype == "U")
                                        {
                                            Session["USERNAME"] = UserName.Text;
                                            Response.Redirect("~/UserHome.aspx");

                                        }

                                        if (Utype == "A")
                                        {
                                            Session["USERNAME"] = UserName.Text;
                                            Response.Redirect("~/AdminHome.aspx");
                                        }

                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    lblError.Text = "Username sau parola invalide";

                                 }

                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would be simpler just to calculate 5 minutes from now `DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)` and then add that value to your database. Then don't allow the user to login if the until the time has been reached - you don't need a timer.

Comment: And how should I stop the user from logging in if I don't use a timeout?

Comment: Check the date from the database (that you generate after 3 failed login attempts). If it is in the future, don't allow the user to login.